# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while reading from Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am getting this error while running the following query in Cassandra 3.11.0:

SELECT JSON * FROM "metrics"."app_36437104577c4432_calculateMetrics" WHERE application = 'app-36437104577c4432' AND user = 'admin' AND session = 'session15'  ALLOW FILTERING;

> ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-10-05 13:47:45,696
>   QueryMessage.java:129 - Unexpected error during query
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.io.JsonStringEncoder.quoteAsString(JsonStringEncoder.java:141)
>   ~[jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.Json.quoteAsJsonString(Json.java:45)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type.toJSONString(UTF8Type.java:66)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.selection.Selection.rowToJson(Selection.java:291)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.selection.Selection$ResultSetBuilder.getOutputRow(Selection.java:431)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.selection.Selection$ResultSetBuilder.newRow(Selection.java:402)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processPartition(SelectStatement.java:823)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.process(SelectStatement.java:759)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processResults(SelectStatement.java:400)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:378)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:251)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:79)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:217)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:248)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:233)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:116)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:517)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:410)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>   [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
>   [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>   [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:162)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131] ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-10-05 13:47:45,697
>   ErrorMessage.java:384 - Unexpected exception during request

```
CREATE TABLE metrics."app_36437104577c4432_calculateMetrics" (
    application text,
    user text,
    session text,
    time timestamp,
    timeid timeuuid,
    execid timeuuid,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((application, user, session), time, timeid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC, timeid ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
   ...;
```

The content of the field text is a long json, and if that field is excluded the query runs successfully.

Any advices?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, It seems that the problem is related to the fact that I am saving the value
 field with a json that is not "scaped". If I  scape the json, the query works properly. I think that this can be considered a bug as the expected behaviour would be to treat the field as a text/string property of the json returned and therefore It should scape it properly.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug with the json encoding stuff to me. Can you please open a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/summary ?

Comment: Yes, I will do. Thanks for your suggestion, although I have to clarify that the fact that scaping the json, fixed the problem is not always true. It worked but in other cases didn't. I am preparing an example for reporting.